# How to show time in seconds greater than 60 in Format("ss")

Tags: vba, powerpoint

When `time- Now()` is less than 60 then `Shapes("countdown").TextFrame.TextRange = Format((time - Now()), "ss")` gives me the output perfectly.

However, when it is greater than 60, say 111, then the output starts with `51` surprisingly. I tried changing the format to `sss` but that definitely didn't work.

I would love your take and suggestions for this. My objective is to have a countdown timer from 111,110,109,...0.

Comment: I found a quick work-around by just adding 60 to the .TextRange: `Format((time - Now()), "ss") + 60`

Comment: `Round( (time - Now()) * (24*60*60), 0)`

Comment: Couldn't you format the cell as `[ss]` - 00:02:00 displays as 120.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for the sake of the next person that find this question, the format can use normal brackets [ ] to show hours, minutes or seconds, over 60 seconds or minutes or 24 hours respectively.

```
Format((time - Now()), "[ss]")
```

Reference:

https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/show-time-over-24-hours-excel/
https://excelchamps.com/formulas/minutes-into-hours/

Answer (score -1):

you can't make "ss" in excel exceded 60, however, you could try to put minutes instead of seconds.

at your statement "However, when it is greater than 60, say 111, then the output starts with 51 surprisingly", it is because 111-60=51, the computer automatically gives you the modulus of your timer on ss, say 61, when you divide 61 by 60, the remaining is 1, so the computer return that value

Comment: Yes, we can definitely use minutes but a pre-requisite is that ONLY seconds is used. I appreciate the explanation regarding the issue.